# Resizing a <canvas> Element

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have the following canvas. I'm trying to make it smaller using the `width` and `height` attributes, but it doesn't work. This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
   <canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="50"></canvas>

    <script>

//set the variables
var a = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    c = a.getContext('2d'),
    w = a.width = window.innerWidth,
    h = a.height = window.innerHeight,
    area = w * h,
    particleNum = 300,
    ANIMATION;

var particles = [];


//create the particles
function Particle(i) {
  this.id = i;
  this.hue =  rand(50, 0, 1);
  this.active = false;
}

Particle.prototype.build = function() {
  this.x = w / 2;
  this.y = h / 2;
  this.r = rand(7, 2, 1);
  this.vx = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
  this.vy = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
  this.gravity = .01;
  this.opacity = Math.random() + .5;
  this.active = true;

  c.beginPath();
      c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  c.fillStyle = "hsla(" + this.hue + ",100%,50%,1)";
  c.fill();
};

Particle.prototype.draw = function() {
  this.active = true;
  this.x += this.vx;
  this.y += this.vy;
  this.vy += this.gravity;
  this.hue -= 0.5;
  this.r = Math.abs(this.r - .05);

  c.beginPath();
      c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  c.fillStyle = "hsla(" + this.hue + ",100%,50%,1)";
  c.fill();

  // reset particle
  if(this.r <= .05) {
    this.active = false;
  }
};


//functionality
function drawScene() {
  c.fillStyle = "black";
  c.fillRect(0,0,w,h);

  for(var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
    if(particles[i].active === true) {
      particles[i].draw();
    } else {
      particles[i].build();
    }
  }

      ANIMATION = requestAnimationFrame(drawScene);
}

function initCanvas() {
  var s = getComputedStyle(a);

  if(particles.length) {
    particles = [];
    cancelAnimationFrame(ANIMATION);
    ANIMATION;
    console.log(ANIMATION);
  }

  w = a.width = window.innerWidth;
    h = a.height = window.innerHeight;

  for(var i = 0; i < particleNum; i++) {
    particles.push(new Particle(i));
  }

  drawScene();
  console.log(ANIMATION);
}


//init
(function() {
  initCanvas();
  addEventListener('resize', initCanvas, false);
})();


//helper functions
function rand(max, min, _int) {
  var max = (max === 0 || max)?max:1, 
      min = min || 0, 
      gen = min + (max - min) * Math.random();

  return (_int) ? Math.round(gen) : gen;
};

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay more attention here:

```
var a = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    c = a.getContext('2d'),
    w = a.width = window.innerWidth,
    h = a.height = window.innerHeight,
    area = w * h,
```

As you can see, `w` is the width of the window and `h` is the height of the window. Try to edit `w` and `h` variable with custom values and tell me if it worked ;)

EDIT:

Simply replace `h` and `w` with this in your script tag:

```
a.style.width = '500px'; //random value, insert custom here
a.style.height = '500px';
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!